# GPU in the cloud - Recording a game

Tags: amazon-web-services, video-streaming, cloud, gpu

Today I had a really great idea for a project, unfortunately there is a information/experience barrier.

What I basically want is to run a game in the cloud and stream the image to the users.

I know that ec2 has the option to use GPU but it may have the wrong pricing model to fit my needs.

---

Run a game in the cloud -> record the screen and send the video feed to a server.

1. Is it possible to run multiple instances of a game on one server and
   be able to stream each instance separately ?
2. Or do I have to start a new instance for every game?

If I would only be able to have one game per instance I would waste many resources. Are there other cloud hosters who offer GPU's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can invest some money to buy a server, you may find Xen Server suitable choice. Xen Server provide GPU virtualization. Xen dedicates a PCI express connection to a virtual node and if your server has multiple GPUs, you can assign them one per virtual node. It works for 3D graphics too.

Comment: you said in another comment that you can get graphics outout with tesla gpu's after 2050. So it is possible with amazon to do this? I read that they use c2050s.

Comment: Yes, they use C2050 but the virtualization technology is under question. Unfortunately, Amazon has not commented on its virtualization technology. If amazon employs a virtualization similar to Xen technology (PCI Passthrough Technology), then there would be no problem with the 3D graphic on it. I guess they use PCI Passthrough-like technology.

Answer (score 3):

First of all: That's really not what Amazon's GPU instances are for. They're primarily aimed at certain high-performance computing tasks which can be accelerated by a GPU, not necessarily at 3D graphics at all.

What you're describing is technically possible; indeed, it's what several companies, including OnLive and Gaikai, have been created to do. However, they have released very few details about the technical aspects of how their service works. All that is clear is that it is **not** simple to set up -- it's not even a given that it's possible with off-the-shelf hardware. (OnLive ended up building out their own data centers, for instance, which is one of the reasons they ended up going under.)

Comment: Oh , I didn't know that. So the GPU is more for something like video converting etc? So I would get really bad performance if I would try to run a game. I would like to test how much performance I would get. Do you think it is possible to run something like 3dmark on ec2? Or would I run into some problems like "no access to 3d graphics", "no directx" etc?

Comment: The GPUs they're using are nVidia Tesla cards, not normal graphics cards; I don't think they even have video outputs. I haven't tried myself, but I doubt that you'd be able to output 3D graphics to them without doing some significant driver work.

Comment: @duskwuff: Recent Tesla GPUs (after C2050) provide graphic output too.

Answer (score 2):

NVIDIA seems to be working on the technology for cloud gaming (and not only gaming). http://www.nvidia.com/object/cloud-gaming.html

There will be a series of talks about NVIDIA GRID technology at this year's GTC in San Jose